# Firebase Security Rules - Access a document field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to check based on a document field, I am trying this:

```
match /usuarios/{user}/{documents=**} {
    allow read, write: if user.data.uid.matches(request.auth.uid)
}
```

I am getting this error

> Invalid type. There is no type for variable 'user' that satisfies all clauses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your document data using resource:

```
match /usuarios/{user}/{documents=**} {
  allow read, write: if resource.data.uid.matches(request.auth.uid)
}
```